# What is an oracle, really?

Tags: computability-theory, mathematical-philosophy

[image: Excerpt from Rogers, Jr., Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Compatibility, pp. 496–497]

Regarding oracles, might this be a reasonable description of their inner workings (this from Hartley Rogers, Jr.'s text, *Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability*)?

Why should I ask such a question in the face of majority opinion to the contrary (as expressed in Prof. Bauer's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405697))?  Well, let me begin at the beginning, with Turing's remarks regarding 'oracles' found in his doctoral thesis, "Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals" (pp. 13–14):

> Let us suppose that we are supplied with some unspecified means of solving number theoretic problems; a kind of oracle as it were.  We will not go any further into the nature of this oracle than to say that it cannot be a machine….

What sort of 'machine' is Turing talking about?  Well, considering that his doctoral thesis was written after the paper that introduced the notion now known as the "Turing Machine", it should be clear from Section 2 of his thesis, "Effective calculability.  Abbreviation of treatment", that it is, in fact, the Turing machine he is referring to in his remarks regarding the oracle.  As regards the notion of "number theoretic problem", he defines it as follows in Section 3, "Number theoretic theorems":

> By a number theoretic theorem we shall mean a theorem of the form '$\theta$ vanishes for infinitely many natural numbers $x$', where $\theta(x)$ is primitive recursive [a primitive recursive function—my comment].  We shall say that a problem is number theoretic if it has been shown that any solution of the problem solution may be put in the form of a proof of one or more number theoretic theorems.  More accurately we may say that a class of problems is number theoretic if the solution of any one of them can be transformed (by a uniform method) into the the form of proofs of number theoretic theorems.

It is within this context I proposed that the generalized machines discussed in Hartley Rogers Jr.'s  book might act as oracles for a certain class of problems (though not in general).

As regards the notion that oracles are merely 'inputs' or a 'database', I refer the reader of this question to a remark made by Martin Davis in his short paper, "Why there is no such discipline as hypercomputation", *Applied Mathematics and Computation* 178 (2006) 4-7:

> The great day has arrived!  The world's first working hypercomputer has been unveiled.  Here comes the output—guaranteed by the engineers to be a non-Turing-computable infinite sequence of natural numbers:
>
> 23, 5, 1267, 111, 59, 87654, 21, 1729, 88888881, etc.
>
> But wait!  No matter how long this goes on, we will see only a finite number of outputs.  Moreover, any such finite sequence of natural numbers is the initial part of both computable and non-computable infinite sequences (in fact, infinitely many of each kind).  Thus, no finite amount of data will suffice to distinguish the computable from the non-computable, and since we, as finite beings with finite lifetimes will only have access to a finite amount of data, no possible experiment could certify that a device is truly going beyond the Turing computable.

Comment: What do you mean with "inner workings"? Usually in computability an oracle is merely a certain string of bits (or a subset of $\mathbb N$, or something equivalent to that effect) which the machine is given access to. It doesn't have to be produced by any supercomputer of any sort.

Comment: Clearly not: as Rogers says, these generalized machines have very limited scope (e.g. the partial functions they compute are exactly the $\Pi^1_1$ ones). So there's no way in which we can think of an *arbitrary* oracle as an instantiation of such a machine. I'm not really sure what this question is getting at, to be honest.

Comment: Better to actually go to the effand type the relevant bit...

Comment: What is the question?  Is it "Might [this quote] be a reasonable description of their [oracles'] inner workings?"  I don't understand how that is a well defined mathematical question.

Comment: @LSpice:  Do you believe that an 'oracle' must be an "(infinite) input string" (as Prof. Bauer holds)?  Given Prof. Davis' observation as quoted by me in my edit, it must, assuming that Prof. Bauer is correct in his assertion.  But the "generalized machine" described by Rogers is as much a 'fiction' as Prof Bauer's 'infinite input string', however,  Prof. Rogers' description of the generalized machine allows that a convergent computation of such a machine can be carried out in a finite amount of time ["Let the unit interval (of real numbers) be thought of as a finite interval of time.   Take

Comment: (cont.) an order-preserving mapping of the Kleene-Brouwer ordering (of our computation) into this interval.  The resulting points may be thought of as moments of time at which steps of the generalized computation occur.  Thus, for example, the generalized machine which solves the ordinary halting problem might, for a given input, perform its steps at times 1/2, 3/4, 7/8,...,1."].  If this quote from Rogers would be deemed a well-defined mathematical description (at least from the point of view of mathematical philosophy), then my question (you got it right in your comment) should be

Comment: (cont.) considered as a "well-defined mathematical question" (at least from the point of view of mathematical philosophy).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

The notion of "inner working" of an oracle is meaningless, because oracles are not machines. They are (infinite) *input strings*.

In fact, it would be better to call oracles just *input*, as that would create less confusion.

Comment: I think this answer is very good, both because it does answer the literal question, and indicates a reframing that explains things even better. And I think the question is worth keeping here, since I'd wager that many people would want to know a precise definition of "oracle", e.g., so one could _prove_ something about it? :)

Comment: @AndrejBauer:  If one was to presume that oracles are just "(infinite) _input strings_" or "just _input_", would one need to presume some sort of background set theory in which these infinite input strings exist and also the existence of functions which would allow one access to these infinite input strings for some Turing machine?

Comment: You are presenting use of "background set theory" as if it were some sort of a problem, which of course it is not. Turing machines themselves are a *mathematical concept* that requires a mathematical background. It's not like we keep them in the basement and wonder where to put the infinite tapes. If you wish, we can separately discuss how strong a formal system is needed to express Turing machines with oracles, but that discussion is orthogonal to the fact that oracles are not machines. Did you see an explanation somewhere that said otherwise?

Comment: I am not so concerned about the necessity of the presumption of a background set theory in order to infer the existence of sets in $\mathcal P$($\omega$) ($\mathcal P$ being the power set) --rather, I am more concerned with the existence of functions necessary to allow one access to the infinite input strings for some Turing machine.  If, say, one would represent those functions as special states for some description of a Turing machine, then they are part of the description of the machine and therefore cannot be claimed to be 'non-mechanical'.  When Turing (in his thesis) claimed that an

Comment: (cont.) oracle "cannot be a machine", what was his definition of 'machine', anyway?

Comment: One common way of having a machine access to an oracle is to have a special read-only "oracle tape" which contains the infinite sequence. The machine may then access the cells on that machine by moving the head around and reading the contents. So we don't have to extend Turing machines with any new concepts, we just give it one more tape. The quesion of where the oracle input comes from or how it is generated is *not* part of the description of a machine with an access to an oracle.

Comment: There are also ways of describing computations relative to an oracle that do not involve any infinite input tapes. Instead, the oracle computation is seen as a (non-computable) limit of a sequence of computations, each of which has acess to a finite approximation of the oracle.

Comment: Are the characterizations given in the last two comments equivalent?  The characterization you give in the last comment is particularly interesting to me in that since "...the oracle computation is seen as a (non-computable) limit of a sequence of computations, each of which has access to a finite approximation of the oracle", it would seem to infer that "the oracle computation...seen as a (non-computable) limit of a sequence of of computations, each of which has access to a finite approximation of the oracle", can be represented as a sequence of computable functions (since each finite

Comment: (cont.) approximation of the oracle in the sequence would be c.e.) with the set of Godel numbers of the sequence of computable functions in question not being c.e. .  How is such "non-mechanical"?

Comment: Roger's book has such a description of oracles. The sequence of approximations is not computable, unless the oracle itself is. The $n$-th approximation receives the first $n$ bits of the oracle *input*, and if it ever atempts to access bits beyond that it diverges.  So the machine is always the same, the changing part is the approximation of the oracle input.